# How to track if emails to my subscribers go to the spam folder instead?

Tags: html

The emails are html formatted and contain info about purchases from my website. I use Google analytics to know my open rates using [this hack](http://dyn.com/blog/tracking-email-opens-via-google-analytics/) and it has come out to be very low. So I was wondering if there was any way to know what percentage of my mails go to the spam folder using Google Analytics itself.

Answer (score 0):

No.

What happens to an email after it leaves your server is more or less completely outside your ability to observe.

About the only exception is watching to see if any URLs (including image srcs) in the email are requested.